# List all records in customer table

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, vba

My Question is, given the following database schema, would this SQL statement let me list all the records for the customer table

[image: Picture of database schema]

The SQL statement I am thinking is simple:

```
Select CustomerId, CustomerFirstname, CustomerLastname, (and so on)
Where Customers
```

Comment: What you actual want ? post desired output and tried query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track! You can answer the question that, to clarify if you did your query would look like:

```
SELECT  CustomerID ,
        CustFirstName ,
        CustLastName ,
        CustStreetAddress ,
        CustCity ,
        CustState ,
        CustZipCode ,
        CustAreaCode ,
        CustPhoneNumber
FROM    Customers;
```

However, an easier way to write this is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
```

Which will list all records, and all columns in the `Customers` table. This isn't something you would normally do in a production system since the performance overhead can be quite onerous, but it's likely what your teacher is seeking for this exercise.

In a real world scenario your `where` clause and joins would limit records, but you can also limit yourself to a particular number of records using something like:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM Customers
```

Which will only show the first 100 records returned by your query.

Comment: How do you know the OP is actually using Access?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't, I know he's using MySQL from how he tagged the question. The first part (which addresses his question directly) is ANSI standard SQL also.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get all records of customer table ?
Not from other 3 tables ?
where is used only when you want condition specific rows.
if you want all columns from customer table

```
select * from Customers;
```

Comment: ask question in comment section ...By MetaTree systems

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the question it seems life you are just trying to spit out all of the rows in the Customers table. If you are trying to do something along those lines try this.

```
select *
from customers;
```